# Why are these item's not displaying inline?

Tags: html, css, header, inline, graphical-logo

I'm working on my header, it's very simple, a logo to the left which is floating left and right next to it, I've been trying to center my elements in the middle of the header.

Everything is working fine, except for some reason the image and elements are not displaying next to eachother.

```css
 nav {
        background-color: #58BEA5;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: -1px;
    }

#logo {
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        float: left;

    }

div.nav-container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
}

a.navitems {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

a.navitems:hover {
    background-color: #3ea38a;
}

#mobbutton {
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 5px;
        margin-top: 1.5%;
    }

**HTML:**
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
        </div>
            <div class="inlineshit">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="img/winkelgidsnulogo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            <img src="img/mobbutton.png" id="mobbutton" alt="mobile button">
            <div class="nav-container">
            <a href="#" class="navitems">HOME</a>
            <a href="#" class="navitems">HANDELAARS</a>
            <a href="#" class="navitems">MEMBERCENTER</a>
            <a href="#contactphone" class="navitems">OVER ONS</a>
            <a href="#" class="navitems">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `.nav-container` is a block element, you need to float it (or `display:inline-block;`) for it to show inline next to other elements

Comment: `display: inline-block` is prefered

Comment: I was typing display: inline-block in all the other div's except for .nav-container.. wow.. Thank you for the fast response @SlavenkoMiljic and Toni Leigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
 nav {
        background-color: #58BEA5;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: -1px;
    }

#logo {
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        float: left;

    }

div.nav-container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
display:inline;
}

a.navitems {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

a.navitems:hover {
    background-color: #3ea38a;
}

#mobbutton {
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 5px;
        margin-top: 1.5%;
    }

**HTML:**
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
        </div>
            <div class="inlineshit">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="img/winkelgidsnulogo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            <img src="img/mobbutton.png" id="mobbutton" alt="mobile button">
            <div class="nav-container">
            <a href="#" class="navitems">HOME</a>
            <a href="#" class="navitems">HANDELAARS</a>
            <a href="#" class="navitems">MEMBERCENTER</a>
            <a href="#contactphone" class="navitems">OVER ONS</a>
            <a href="#" class="navitems">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

```css
 nav {
        background-color: #58BEA5;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: -1px;
    }

#logo {
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        float: left;

    }

div.nav-container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
}

a.navitems {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

a.navitems:hover {
    background-color: #3ea38a;
}

#mobbutton {
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 5px;
        margin-top: 1.5%;
    }

**HTML:**
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
        </div>
            <div class="inlineshit">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="img/winkelgidsnulogo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            <img src="img/mobbutton.png" id="mobbutton" alt="mobile button">
            <div class="nav-container">
            <a href="#" class="navitems">HOME</a>
            <a href="#" class="navitems">HANDELAARS</a>
            <a href="#" class="navitems">MEMBERCENTER</a>
            <a href="#contactphone" class="navitems">OVER ONS</a>
            <a href="#" class="navitems">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```